# Range Slider Choppy, not updating on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making a range slider in React, using jsx and some css. Right now, my slider is filled on the left side, will follow the slider thumb to be filled, but is very choppy. Meaning, when you move the slider around, the fill from the left side overflows or doesn't actually make it all of the way and has to catch up with the thumb. Also, when you click on the somewhere in the slider without first using the thumb, the fill does not update. I'm not sure why this is happening, so I'm having a very hard time fixing it. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type='range'] {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 1%);
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 450ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
}
```

Babel:

```
class VolumeSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 600
    };
  }

  onUpdate(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }
 
  onInput(e){
    const gradStart = (this.state.value/e.target.max/2)*100;
    const gradEnd = (this.state.value/e.target.max)*100;
    e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, red 0%,  red ' + gradStart + '%, red ' + gradEnd + '%, #fff 1%)';
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          list="tickmarks"
          max={1200}
          onChange={(e) => this.onUpdate(e)}
          onInput={(e) => this.onInput(e)}
          step={0.1}
          type="range"
          value={this.state.value}
        />
           <label className="c-label">{this.state.value}c</label>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <VolumeSlider />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here's my codepen for refrence: https://codepen.io/kcandle/pen/qBNLMQE

Answer (score 1):

You are fighting against the way React works. If you want to update the React component, it should really be in `render()`. Directly accessing `e.target` is going around React's idea of how it should be updated.

```js
//jsx edited:

class VolumeSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 600
    };
    this.max = 1200
  }
 
  onInput(e){
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
    
  }
  
  render() {
     const gradStart = (this.state.value/this.max/2)*100;
    const gradEnd = (this.state.value/this.max)*100;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          list="tickmarks"
          max={1200}
          onChange={(e) => this.onInput(e)}
          onInput={(e) => this.onInput(e)}
          step={0.1}
          type="range"
          style={{background: 'linear-gradient(to right, red 0%,  red ' + gradStart + '%, red ' + gradEnd + '%, #fff 1%)'}}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
           <label className="c-label">{this.state.value}c</label>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <VolumeSlider />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right I'm sure. I'm not sure how I could do that with this though. Sorry, very new to the framework.

Comment: Added the code example. Remove the style:background from the CSS, and render it with style={{background: 'css here'}} in the render() and remove any code accessing `e.target` in `onUpdate` and `onInput`... which means they are the same now, no need for both. Just use each to `setState()`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! This makes a lot of sense, idk why I thought to use e.target hahaha. Have a good day!

Comment: Hi again! I'm noticing that the choppyness of the slider still isn't fixed somehow. Is this because of my other e.target for the numbers? I tried moving them to see if that helped but it did not. Any thoughts help- thanks!

Comment: do you mean using `e.target.value` inside the `setState`? I don't think so. When I paste the new JSX into the codepen it works great (MacBook Air Safari 14). What are you trying this on?